How can I keep only one value of all redundant ones in a column in data frame?
I am finding difficulty to filter out a column in data frame in R to keep only just one value of a its identical ones. For example: in this data Datain the column named "Assembly_ID", I would like to keep only one record of those that are repeated with their corresponding columns, for instance to only
GCF_037000505.1
GCF_004127345.1
GCF_004127375.1
and so on... while keeping their column info.
To be honest I have not find any function in R to do this.
Thanks

Thanks I managed to do it: Here is what I did

For the benifit of everybody, I am positing the way I did it:
To deduplicating some row,
install.packages(c('tidyverse', 'janitor', 'stringr'))
library(tidyverse) 
library(janitor)
library(stringr)

rownames(Data)<- Data$Assembly.Accession

Remove the duplicated row based n the column"Assembly.accession", but keeping all other column after removal
Data_uniq<- Data %>% 
  distinct(Assembly.Accession, .keep_all = TRUE)

keep rows unique by name and purpose, retain all columns
